# System.gc() in Codename One

Tags: codenameone

Does `System.gc()` (https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/java/lang/System.html#gc--) do something in Codename One, or doesn't?

I tried it in a Codename One app while profiling Ram in XCode, but `System.gc()` seems ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.gc()` is implemented but it's asynchronous as the GC is a separate thread. You shouldn't invoke it normally as it can really hit performance badly. What we don't support is measuring the amount of available RAM. That's a bit hard to do in a multi-tasking OS. Java tricks this by using `Xmx` flags but that's just silly since we'd want to keep taking up RAM the OS has for us. If the OS sends a RAM low event we run the GC implicitly.

Comment: Shai, what do you think of this JAnton's answer just added? https://stackoverflow.com/a/73115860/1277576. If it's true, then ParparVM seems bugged.

Comment: It's wrong and ignores the finalizer problem in gcs. Objects that have finalizers which is pretty much every object representing native elements can't be gcd in the first round and need more work. 400ms is an arbitrary number that assumes it knows how the VM implemented GC. It's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior of `System.gc()`.

- It may perform a garbage collection synchronously.
- It may trigger an asynchronous garbage collection.
- It may be completely ignored.

What actually happens is platform dependent, and depends on the JVM options.  For example, there is a JVM option than instructs the JVM to *completely ignore* calls to `System.gc()`.

---

However, this should be moot.

Calling `System.gc()` is a bad idea in most circumstances:

- It is inefficient.  Indeed, in the worst case it is horribly inefficient.
- If you are doing it because your application is running out of space, it won't help.
- If you are doing it because you have a memory leak, it won't help.
- If you are doing it because you have a resource leak, it may not help.
- If you are trying to encourage the JVM to "give memory back" to the OS, it probably won't help.  (It typically takes a few full GC cycles before the JVM will give memory back.  And if your application's heap requirements are cyclic, the JVM is liable to ask the OS for the memory again.)

There are better (more effective, more effective) solutions to the above problems in most circumstances.  For example, getting more physical memory, increasing the heap size, or finding and fixing the memory and resource leaks.

In general, it is best to let the JVM itself manage the garbage collection.  It can do it better than your application can ... in most situations.

Answer (score 1):

There is one case where calling `System.gc()` makes sense: when you have a background thread that is processing large strings (>20MB) on iOS, it is useful to call `System.gc()` and pace the thread with a 400ms sleep before proceeding to the next chunk. This is because the VM (Parpar) will often crash when too much data is processed too quickly (again it usually happens when trying to process more than 20MB at once).

The root cause could be that the VM isn't aggressive/fast enough in cleaning up out-of-scope variables and ends up filling whatever internal limit it has for its heap. This is speculation as I don't know the specifics of the VM; I only know the effects it has on stability

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56904567/system-gc-in-codename-one/56911317#comment129135877_56911317

Comment: 400ms is definitely arbitrary, I agree. All I know is that it works in my case and prevents crashes

Comment: This can be used to prevent VM crashes on iOS when dealing with large strings... call `StringThrottle.run([large string])` after creating each large string. The class has configurable params. They currently are set so that processing more than 5MB in less than 4 seconds triggers a call to GC and a pause of 400ms
https://gist.github.com/javieranton-zz/ca83c2a9baeeb447fd95bccd4f47ff77